# PayPal Error: “Your payment can’t be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again”

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I integrated `Paypal Adaptive Payments` but when a user click on the buy button the user gets the `PayPal Error: “Your payment can’t be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again”`. On the server side the paykey is created:

```
pay: {"responseEnvelope":{"timestamp":"2012-08-03T00:17:58.697-07:00","ack":"Success","correlationId":"c830d0b683474","build":"DEV"},"payKey":"AP-XXXXXXXXXXX,"paymentExecStatus":"CREATED"}
```

It works in sandbox but not live. Anyone faced that problem?
Thanks

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this problem, see my answer on [Chained payment cannot be completed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26984099/3917091). I'm hesitant to flag any of these questions as duplicates because people find different reasons for the cause of this very vague answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. In my client code, I was referring to the sandbox URL instead of the live URL.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame">
  <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
  <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-...">
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal">
</form>
```